# IMPORT RANGE with Spreadsheet ID or URL in next cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

Not an advanced user of Google Sheets by any means. I've successfully imported ranges from various workbooks into a list using a combination of QUERY and IMPORTRANGE. What I'm missing is a way to identify in the list where the imported data has come from. I'd like for the cell next to each row of imported data to have either a unique ID, the spreadsheet URL or the name of the sheet as a text string.

Any help is appreciated.

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!F3:F100");IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!e3:e60");IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!e3:e70")},"where Col1 is not null")
```

Comment: On every row you can add a range name like: `{"'Approved Content Master'!F3:F100", IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!F3:F100"); ...}`. Or just give it a sensible name.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!F3:F100"), Z3:Z100&"Sheet1";
 IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!E3:E60"),  Z3:Z60 &"Sheet3";
 IMPORTRANGE("url","'Approved Content Master'!E3:E70"),  Z3:Z70 &"Sheet3"},
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

where Z column is empty